# Multithreaded Item Price Checking server in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, client-server, distributed-system

I am trying to implement a multithreaded item price checking server, where I have two classes : A Server and A Client. My Server should also have access to a file where it will hold items with respective prices, and my client should be able to ask for an item "ex. Coffee" and get its price from server "ex. $2.00". Now I don't know how to make a file and extract required information, so need help.

Here is my Server Code:

```
import java.io.{DataInputStream, DataOutputStream}
import java.net.ServerSocket
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
object server extends App {
  // Register service on port 9000
   val server = new ServerSocket(9000)
  while(true) {
    // Register service on port 1234
        val socket = server.accept()
    Future {
      //store local socket references for processing
            val client = socket
      try {
        // Get a communication stream associated with the socket
                val is = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream())
        // Get a communication stream associated with the socket
                val os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())
        // Read from input stream
               var line: String = is.readLine()
        // sending string
                os.writeBytes("$2.00\n")
                println(line)
       } catch {
        case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
      } finally {
        // Close the connection, but not the server socket
                client.close()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Here is my Client Code:

```
import java.io.{DataInputStream, DataOutputStream}
import java.net.Socket
object client extends App {
  var client: Option[Socket] = None
  try {
  //Open your connection to a server, at port 9000
    client = Some(new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000))
    // Get an input file handle from the socket
    val is = new DataInputStream(client.get.getInputStream)
    val os = new DataOutputStream(client.get.getOutputStream)
    // write to server a string
    //os.writeBytes("Hello from client\n")
    os.writeBytes("Coffee\n")
    //read from server a string
    var line: String = is.readLine()
    //printing output
    println(line)
  }
  catch {
     case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
  }
  finally {
    client foreach (_.close())
  }

}
```